так... что..., как... syntax
I'm having trouble understanding this from РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ 1924:

Въ Россіи муки такъ велики, что человѣческое воображеніе ихъ не
вмѣщаетъ, какъ не можемъ мы себѣ представить ни такого страшнаго
грѣха, для котораго онѣ могли бы служить искупленіемъ, ни такого
великаго блага, которое могло бы ихъ окупить

I could understand так велики, что.... or так велики, как... but here we have two subordinate clauses. I may have misunderstood, but I think both subordinate clauses are governed by так? так велики, что человеческое воображение их не вмещает and так велики, как не можем мы себе преставить.
Or maybe the punctuation is wrong? Въ Россіи муки такъ велики, что человѣческое воображеніе ихъ не вмѣщаетъ--какъ не можемъ мы себѣ представить ни такого страшнаго грѣха, для котораго онѣ могли бы служить искупленіемъ!
In fact, I don't really know why I can't work this out, but there seems to be something wrong with the sentence.

Or maybe как just means "as" and doesn't connect in any other way to what goes before it.

Here, как is a synonym for так как or потому что "because".
The phrase means: "In Russia the suffering is so great that the human imagination cannot encompass it, because we can imagine neither a sin so grave it (the suffering) could serve as a redemption for, nor a benefit so great it could pay it (the suffering) off"
In this sense, как is dated, and mostly known from the Synodal translation of the Bible, especially the New Testament.


Но как они, познав Бога, не прославили Его, как Бога, и не возблагодарили, но осуетились в умствованиях своих, и омрачилось несмысленное их сердце
Because that, when they knew God, they glorified him not as God, neither were thankful; but became vain in their imaginations, and their foolish heart was darkened (Romans 1:21)

… но как они не имели чем заплатить, он простил обоим
And when they had nothing to pay, he frankly forgave them both (Luke 7:42)



A similar construct in English would be "for" in the sense of "because", like in "For they eat the bread of wickedness, and drink the wine of violence"

"Because that" is also archaic in English. I normally translate "for" by ибо. I see the point now. окупить could "to make up for".

I meant to write: окупить could BE TRANSLATED "to make up for".

@pompey1969: if you see any obvious mistakes in my English, please feel free to edit. Thank you!

I will if I see any.

Въ Россіи муки такъ велики, что человѣческое воображеніе ихъ не вмѣщаетъ, какъ не можемъ мы себѣ представить ни такого страшнаго грѣха, для котораго онѣ могли бы служить искупленіемъ, ни такого великаго блага, которое могло бы ихъ окупить
Whereas так is connected with что (настолько, что), как is connected with представить (simple comparison), so the meaning seems to be the following
В России муки так (=настолько) велики, (как велики муки?) что их невозможно представить, как(=и точно так же) невозможно представить греха, для которого эти муки могли служить искуплением...
... torments are so great that you can't imagine them as well as the sin for which these torments could serve as redemption...
